# how to make foreach loop in MVC to set new value to items.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, foreach

im trying to do loop throw objects in clas and check its data tybe
and make control, if the data type is string so i want this item value to be empty. 
and if the data type is int so the value of this item is 0 and so on.

here my pseudo code

```
 ProductionOrderItem i = new ProductionOrderItem();

 foreach( ProductionOrderItem item in i)
        {
              if(item.data type is string)
              {
                  item.value = "" ;
              }
              if ((item.data type is int)
              {
                item.value = 0 ;
              }

              if (item.data type is stringDateTime))
              {
                  item.value = 2011-01-01 00:00:00;
              }
           else
               // do any thing. 

        }
```

or is it possible to put the item into array and make lopp though th array ?

Comment: your code isn't very clear, you are declaring a single instance of a class then trying to iterate through that single instance as if it were a collection? I don't think this would even compile? not to mention weird opening and closing parenthesis in odd locations.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach can iterate only on collections! The i variable in this case may be a list like this:

```
 List<ProductionOrderItem> i = new List<ProductionOrderItem>();
```

Now you can iterate on it. The foreach iterate through the list:

```
 foreach( ProductionOrderItem item in i)
        {
              if(item.data type is string)
              {
                  item.value = "" ;
              }
              if ((item.data type is int)
              {
                item.value = 0 ;
              }

              if (item.data type is stringDateTime))
              {
                  item.value = 2011-01-01 00:00:00;
              }
           else
               // do any thing. 

        }
```

But remember: don't change the variable i within the loop.

Comment: item.value = "" ;   is wrong, what is the correct syntax for this is my question

Comment: The item is an instance of ProductionOrderItem type. May be the ProductionOrderItem class doesnt have Value property. Please write me this ProductionOrderItem class implementation.